# Yii2 REST API Multiple browser login

Tags: api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can anyone help me how to login from multiple browser using REST API using the access token?
If entry is present in accesstoken table for same browser its overwrite but enter new record for another browser
Thanks

Comment: Do not understand the use of browsers for a REST API !?! or how you make use of an accesstoken table.

Comment: @karpy47 how use type field in accesstoken table

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. Show your problem in code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the answer

```
 Yii::$app->request->getUserAgent();
```